# Reduce the weight of a high resolution image online

Tags: image-resizing

I am in need of a high resolution images but that is not the problem.I have many high resolution images which are truly free online but their weight is a hinderance for use on the web.For instance,a good image with 1920px by 1080px is weighing in at 1.2mb yet i see images of similar dimensions i.e http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3241/3096487740_ebb4ea9819_o.jpg that weigh a lot less (175kb).

Is there a suitable and reliable web service that can help me reduce the weight of a big image like http://www.rgbstock.com/filedownload/krappweis/nX2zg5e.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use IrfanView and it's advanced saving options? You can compress images quite good with it and you can also delete informational data, which is not important for the image to display.

Comment: I am behind a proxy and that web service is blocked along with many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.When looking to reduce the weight of an image,don't google 'reduce size'.Also read carefully what free image compression web service is being offered.Some will ruin and have ruined my images.

I finally found this web service http://compressnow.com/